# How to get data results from mysql query along with count of rows returned with query?

Tags: mysql

The query below returns all the values from the query, but I also need the total rows returned from the query in a column.  It can be the same value in each row.

I have tried using COUNT(), but it returns a 1 in every row. "COUNT(A.MRN) as ReturnedRows" in the select and "GROUP BY A.MRN"  after the where

```
select A.STATUS as ASTATUS, A.MRN as StatusMRN, 
K.transnumber, K.NRM as PatientMRN, K.DESCRIPTION
from  database_name.patientoverlay as K
inner join database_name.patientstatus as A on A.MRN = K.MRN
where A.STATUS like'active' and K.description like '%Overlaypreformed%';
```

This what the query returns:

```
ASTATUS StatusMRN   transnumber   PatientMRN   DESCRIPTION
active  12356789    78000         12356789     Overlay performed
active  12356791    78001         12356791     Overlay performed
active  12356792    78002         12356792     Overlay performed
active  12356793    78003         12356793     Overlay performed
active  12356794    78004         12356794     Overlay performed
```

I know that there are 110 active patients in the patientstaus table, and them MySQL tool states it returned 110 rows.

I would like to get the following:

```
ASTATUS StatusMRN   transnumber   PatientMRN   DESCRIPTION       ReturnedRows
active  12356789    78000     12356789     Overlay performed     110
active  12356791    78001     12356791     Overlay performed     110
active  12356792    78002     12356792     Overlay performed     110
active  12356793    78003     12356793     Overlay performed     110
active  12356794    78004     12356794     Overlay performed     110
```

Comment: What in heaven's name is `p`

Comment: why not just run a separate count query, if you need that information?

Comment: The external system is limiting me to one query

Comment: What is this external system? I never heard of an application where you could only run one query.